# How add Static Web Content in Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to add static web content in a spring-boot server using the info [here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)

I have tried adding the .js and .css files I need in the several Folders that the previous link says but it doesn't work:

> ```
> /META-INF/resources/
> /resources/
> ```

Note: I didn't created the `/static/` and `/public/` folders because I don't know the absolute Path in my project.

I have added too the `addResourceHandlers` method:

> ```
> @Override
> public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
> if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
>     registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
>             "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
> }
> if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
>     registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(
>             RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
> }
> }
> ```

And the reference in the HTML file are like this:

`<script src="bootstrap-switch.js"></script>`
Any idea how I can fix that?

**UPDATED**:

[image]

UPDATED 2: trying the @jfcorugedo

Doesnt work. Take a look, is that what was you saying?

[image]

UPDATED 3:trying the @jfcorugedo, second advice:

[image]

Comment: Try access the file using /application-context/js/bootstrap-switch.js

Comment: For your second update, you should not insert META-INF in src. Its enough <script src="js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script> or <script src="/<myapp>/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>

Comment: It doesn't work Danilo.

Comment: please find answer @ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788459/spring-boot-static-content-with-context-path/54112835#54112835](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788459/spring-boot-static-content-with-context-path/54112835#54112835)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you should access static contents using `mydomain/<context>/<resource type>/resource`

For instance:

```
http://mydomain/app/js/test.js
http://mydomain/app/img/test.jpg
```

You can write your resources using application context or simply using relative path:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="/<myapp>/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

But if you are using bootstrap with a webjar you should write

```
<script src="/<myapp>/webjars/bootstrap/<version>/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

There is a project on github to illustrate this
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static

UPDATE [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnNmy.png)

I created a test project with the follow structure:

[image]

I could access style.css on http://localhost:8080/css/style.css

You can use http://start.spring.io/ to help you create new projects

Another option is use Spring Tool Suite or IntelliJ IDEA.
They can help you to create new project with right configurations (as the previous link).

Comment: ok and have I to copy the files in which folder's project? I have copied them in `/project_name/src/main/resources/META-INF/js` and `/project_name/src/main/resources/META-INF/css`  but that doesnt work.

Comment: I have updated with a screenshot. Please could you confirm that the two issues are correct? Should I change something of my `addResourceHandlers`? It doesn't work.

Comment: Try use js/bootstrap-switch.js and css/bootstrap-switch.css in your references

Comment: Try put your files in src/main/resources/static. I've created a new project here, and that's seems the most intuitive way

Comment: I updated with a screenshot of my test project and some enw advices

Comment: This update is perfect! works like a charm! Thank you Danilo!

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to add the method addResourceHandlers, Spring boot executes this method in its own code.

**Don't put the files inside webapp folder**.

You only need to put your files in one of these directories:

`/META-INF/resources/
/resources/
/static
/public`

For instance, if you want to load the file `js/bootstrap-switch.js`, this file must be in one of those folders:

`/META-INF/resources/js/bootstrap-switch.js
/resources/js/bootstrap-switch.js
...`

I've created a folder META-INF/resources/js inside my /src/main/resources and everything works:

[image: folder hierarchy in my test project]

I've put a test.js file inside this folder and, when I've type the URL http://localhost:8080/js/test.js the application has given me the JS file.

Are you sure you're creating this same folder hierarchy?

Comment: so the absolute path on the server for that is: /project/src/main/META-INF/ ? or just /project/META-INF ?

Comment: You have to use this one: src/main/resources/META-INF/

Don't put resources inside src/main, because maven, by default, only recognises files inside src/main/java and src/main/resources

Comment: I tried too without success. The server gives me an 404 as always... My knowledge about Spring-boot is very poor but , maybe this information help us: I have built the project with Gradle, I use TomCat 7 and I run that as a JavaApplication.

Comment: Just a note that "static" did not work for me.......but "resources" did......I"m talking about the 2nd "resources"..aka, the more deeply nested one.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties` class, you can see this line of code:

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = new String[]{"classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"};
```

Meaning `/META-INF/resources/`, `/resources/`, `static/` and `public/` directories are available to serve static contents.

So you can create a `static/` or `public/` directory under `resources/` directory and put your static contents there. And they will be accessible by: `http://localhost:8080/your-file.ext`. (assuming the `server.port` is 8080)

You can customize these directories using `spring.resources.static-locations` in the `application.properties`.

For example by providing this configuration:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/custom/
```

You can use `custom/` folder under `resources/` for serving static files and access them through the URL above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder anywhere with a /static folder on the root.  This can be anywhere on your work space.  Example C:\mywebapp\static.  Add C:\mywebapp to the runtime classpath, or if using Intellij/Eclipse, add the folder C:\mywebapp as a library.

This is different than adding your static html as a source folder, which will cause it be be copied to the output class folder with every build.  If you have a large web app or single page app using angular or sencha, this is a pain.
Instead add the folder C:\mywebapp as a library folder or run time classpath folder.

The benefit of this is it will allow your javascript code to run on the same host/port as your spring boot rest,ajax, etc services without having to deal with jsonp or cors.

Comment: How do you add C:\mywebapp to the classpath at runtime ?