# Spring Boot static content with context path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having problems with static content in Spring Boot when using a context path. i.e.: I wish to deploy my app to `localhost:8080/{appname}/`

When I run the app without context path everything works fine and Spring Boot finds and runs my `.html` files (from resources/templates/, I'm using `Thymeleaf`) and JS files (from resources/static/js/) but when I add the context path with either:

```
server.context-path=/{appname}
```

OR

```
server.servlet-path=/{appname}
```

then the `.html` pages are still displayed by the JS files generate **404 errors**.

I have tried to change the `spring.resources.static-locations` in the `application.properties` and overriding `addResourceHandlers()` method in my `MvcConfig.class` but neither seem to work

I use a `MvcConfig` class because I need to define a `CookieLocaleResolver` and a `MessageSource` but that is all I have in the `MvcConfig`. I do not use `@EnableWebMvc` and just have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation with a `@ComponentScan`.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you paste youre configuration and drectory structure?

Comment: Is it that the expected URL for the js file is 404ing? or the JS file referenced by the HTML is 404ing? (e.g. is the problem that the HTML is referencing the JS without the app context, or something else)

Comment: @rhinds the HTML is referencing the JS without the app context

Comment: For future reference I will just add a quick comment here since I reckon many people use the combination of spring-boot and react clients. I had the exact same symptoms with react and resolved it by setting `homepage` in `package.json` with the same string as I used to set `context-path` in `application.yml`. I.e. `context-path: /foobar` has to be accompanied with `"homepage": "/foobar"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comment:

> the HTML is referencing the JS without the app context

the problem is not in Spring serving the js, its that the page is not creating the URL to the resources correctly.

Thymeleaf provides a mechanism to support this automatically by just marking the src attribute with the `th` prefix.

See section 2 "Context-relative URLs": [www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Comment: That solved the problem, thx! I had actually done a test with the @{/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js} before but I think something else was broken too and I replaced it with a normal <script src=""> instead for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example shows how to configure static resources in spring boot.

[image]

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*.js").addResourceLocations("/ui/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*.css").addResourceLocations("/ui/static/");
    }
}
```

Path patterns

Add a resource handler for serving static resources based on the specified URL path patterns. The handler will be invoked for every incoming request that matches to one of the specified path patterns.

Patterns like "/static/**" or "/css/{filename:\w+\.css}"} are allowed.
See **org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher** for more details on the syntax.

your jsp/html looks refer static content as in below

```
<link href="/webAppContext/cssa/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/webAppContext/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webAppContext/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

urls using which browser tries to get static content

```
http://localhost:8080/webAppContext/jquery-2.2.1.min.js
http://localhost:8080/webAppContext/bootstrap.min.js
http://localhost:8080/webAppContext/cssa/bootstrap.min.css


server.servlet.context-path=/webAppContext is in your application.properties
```

Answer (score -2):

My config is:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MvcConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("language");
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(-1);
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/lang");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new Urli18nRewriterInterceptor());
    }   
}
```

and folder structure:

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdiVi.jpg)

Comment: You should'nt add your configuration as an answer, you should add it to your question.