# Spring Boot - can not include static resource

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Directory structure

[image]

I try include css in profile.html

```
<link th:href="@{css/profile.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But this doesn't work

My Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: have you tried static/css/profile.css

Comment: please take a look to this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018892/how-add-static-web-content-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

this is a good example if you are trying to start with static content with jsp pages.

I hope this can help

[spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)